# Changed IIS directory in DotNetNuke leads to portal enumeration problems

Tags: iis, dotnetnuke, portal, virtual-directory

I moved the files in my DNN Community Edition (5.6) to another disk with the same path.  I adjusted the IIS server's home directory's local path to new location (from C: to D:).

When going to the home page the server fails, unable to find the portals associated with the website:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   DotNetNuke.Common.Initialize.CacheMappedDirectory() in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\DotNetNuke_Community\DotNetNuke_Community_05.06.05_Source\Library\Common\Initialize.vb:59
   DotNetNuke.Common.Initialize.InitializeApp(HttpApplication app) in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\DotNetNuke_Community\DotNetNuke_Community_05.06.05_Source\Library\Common\Initialize.vb:149
   DotNetNuke.Common.Initialize.Init(HttpApplication app) in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\DotNetNuke_Community\DotNetNuke_Community_05.06.05_Source\Library\Common\Initialize.vb:228
   DotNetNuke.Common.Global.Global_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\DotNetNuke_Community\DotNetNuke_Community_05.06.05_Source\Website\App_Code\Global.asax.vb:135    
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +148
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

The web.config had no absolute paths in it.  So, I've turned my attention to the database for setting the path for Portal 0, my only portal.

I've tried modifying the Home Directory entry in Table from Portals/0 to D:/Inetpub/wwwroot/DotNetNuke_Community/DotNetNuke_Community_05.06.05_Source/Website/Portals/0
without luck.

Your suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check is to make sure you have the proper permissions configured on the new folder. You shouldn't need to change the HomeDirectory entry.